# How to set data to @Input declared variable by service response using angular2

Tags: angular

i am using "ng2-smart-table". in "ng2-smart-table.component.ts" i have

```
import {
  Component, Input, Output, SimpleChange, EventEmitter,
  OnChanges
} from '@angular/core';

import { Grid } from './lib/grid';
import { DataSource } from './lib/data-source/data-source';
import { Row } from './lib/data-set/row';

import { deepExtend } from './lib/helpers';
import { LocalDataSource } from './lib/data-source/local/local.data-source';

import { ViewListCustomersComponent} from '../app/view-list-customers/view-list-customers.component';
import any = jasmine.any;

@Component({
  selector: 'ng2-smart-table',
  styles: [require('./ng2-smart-table.scss')],
  template: require('./ng2-smart-table.html')
  //template: require('../app/view-list-customers/ng2-smart-table.html')
})

export class Ng2SmartTableComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() source: any;
  @Input() settings: Object = {};

  @Output() public rowSelect: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() public userRowSelect: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() public delete: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() public edit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() public create: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  @Output() public deleteConfirm: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() public editConfirm: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() public createConfirm: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  @Input() defaultSettings:Object;

  @Input() customerDetailsItem : Object;
  data:Array<string>;
  protected grid: Grid;

  constructor(public viewListCustomersComponent:ViewListCustomersComponent) {
    console.log("==isEdit======== "+this.source);
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: {[propertyName: string]: SimpleChange}): void {
    console.log("=================ngOnChanges=================");
    if (this.grid) {
      if (changes['settings']) {
        this.grid.setSettings(this.prepareSettings());
      }
      if (changes['source']) {
        this.grid.setSource(this.source);
      }
    } else {
      this.initGrid();
    }

  }

  onAdd(event): boolean {
    console.log("=================onAdd=================");
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (this.grid.getSetting('mode') === 'external') {
      this.create.emit({
        source: this.source
      });
    } else {
      this.grid.createFormShown = true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  onUserSelectRow(row: Row): void {
    console.log("=================onUserSelectRow=================");
    this.grid.selectRow(row);
    this.userRowSelect.emit({
      data: row.getData(),
      source: this.source
    });

    this.onSelectRow(row);
  }

  onSelectRow(row: Row): void {
    console.log("=================onSelectRow=================");
    this.grid.selectRow(row);
    this.rowSelect.emit({
      data: row.getData(),
      source: this.source
    });
  }

  onEdit(row: Row, event): boolean {
    console.log("=================onEdit=================");
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.onSelectRow(row);

    if (this.grid.getSetting('mode') === 'external') {
      this.edit.emit({
        data: row.getData(),
        source: this.source
      });
    } else {
      this.grid.edit(row);
    }
    return false;
  }

  onDelete(row: Row, event): boolean {
    console.log("=================onDelete=================");
    event.stopPropagation();

    if (this.grid.getSetting('mode') === 'external') {
      this.delete.emit({
        data: row.getData(),
        source: this.source
      });
    } else {
      this.grid.delete(row, this.deleteConfirm);
    }
    return false;
  }

  onCreate(row: Row, event): boolean {
    console.log("=================onCreate=================")
    event.stopPropagation();

    this.grid.create(row, this.createConfirm);
    return false;
  }

  onSave(row: Row, event): boolean {
    console.log("=================onSave================="+row.getCells()[0].getValue());

    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("dddddddddddd "+this.viewListCustomersComponent.onCustomerEdit(row.getCells()));
    //this.grid.save(row, this.editConfirm);
    return false;
  }

  onActive(row: Row, event): boolean {
    console.log("=================onActive=================");
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.grid.save(row, this.editConfirm);
    return false;
  }
  protected initGrid(): void {
    this.source = this.prepareSource();
    this.grid = new Grid(this.source, this.prepareSettings());
    this.grid.onSelectRow().subscribe((row) => this.onSelectRow(row));
  }

  protected prepareSource(): DataSource {
    if (this.source instanceof DataSource) {
      return this.source;
    } else if (this.source instanceof Array) {
      return new LocalDataSource(this.source);
    }

    return new LocalDataSource();
  }

  protected prepareSettings(): Object {
    console.log("============this.settings======="+this.settings)
    return deepExtend({}, this.defaultSettings, this.settings);
  }
}
```

and in my app.compont.html i have written

```
<ng2-smart-table  [settings]="settings" [source]="data" [defaultSettings]="defaultSettings" [customerDetailsItem]="customerDetailsItem"></ng2-smart-table>
```

and in my app.componebt.ts file have

```
data : CustomerDetailsItem[];
constructor(public service:ViewListCustomerServiceService) 
{
  this.service.getCustomerItemList().subscribe(lst =>this.data=(lst));
}
```

but in browser console i am getting empty table and excption

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./appComponent class appComponent - inline template:70:100 caused by: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'source.setPaging(1, this.getSetting('pager.perPage'), false)')
```

main.bundle.js:50314ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'source.setPaging(1, this.getSetting('pager.perPage'), false)')
main.bundle.js:50321

if i pass static vaule to "data" variable then i am getting table with default data.
eg.

```
data=[
{

  id:1,

  "name":"Customer 1",

  "details":"Customer 1",

  "active":false

},

{

  "id":2,

  "name":"Customer 2",

  "details":"Customer 2 details goes here",

  "active":false

}];
```

and i also checked from my service response same like above.

please suggest me what should i do.

here is my app.Component.service.ts code

```
@Injectable()
export class appComponentService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  getCustomerItemList():Observable<CustomerDetailsItem[]> {

    let response = this.http.get(`${AppSettings.BACK_ENDPOINT}/nextrow/list-customers/?access_token=`+sessionStorage.getItem("access_token"));
    let customerDetailItems = response.map(mapCustomerItems);
    return customerDetailItems;
  }
}
function mapCustomerItems(response:Response):CustomerDetailsItem[] {
  let customerDetailsItem =response.json();
  return customerDetailsItem;
}
```

**ng2-smart-table.html**

```
<div class="ng2-smart-table-container">
```

```
<tr class="ng2-smart-titles" *ngIf="!grid.getSetting('hideHeader')">
  <th *ngIf="grid.showActionColumn('left')" class="ng2-smart-actions">
    <div class="ng2-smart-title">{{ grid.getSetting('actions.columnTitle') }}</div>
  </th>
  <th *ngFor="let column of grid.getColumns()" class="ng2-smart-th {{ column.id }}" [ngClass]="column.class">
    <div class="ng2-smart-title">
      <ng2-smart-table-title [source]="source" [column]="column"></ng2-smart-table-title>
    </div>
  </th>
  <th *ngIf="grid.showActionColumn('right')" class="ng2-smart-actions">
    <div class="ng2-smart-title">{{ grid.getSetting('actions.columnTitle') }}</div>
  </th>
</tr>
```

```
<tr *ngIf="grid.createFormShown">
  <td class="ng2-smart-actions">
    <a href="#" class="ng2-smart-action ng2-smart-action-add-create" [innerHTML]="grid.getSetting('add.createButtonContent')" (click)="onCreate(grid.getNewRow(), $event)"></a>
    <a href="#" class="ng2-smart-action ng2-smart-action-add-cancel" [innerHTML]="grid.getSetting('add.cancelButtonContent')" (click)="grid.createFormShown = false;"></a>
  </td>
  <td *ngFor="let cell of grid.getNewRow().getCells()">
    <ng2-smart-table-cell [cell]="cell" [inputClass]="grid.getSetting('add.inputClass')" (edited)="onCreate(grid.getNewRow(), $event)"></ng2-smart-table-cell>
  </td>
</tr>

</thead>

<tbody>

<tr *ngFor="let row of grid.getRows()" (click)="onUserSelectRow(row)" class="ng2-smart-row" [ngClass]="{selected: row.isSelected}">
  <td *ngIf="!row.isInEditing && grid.showActionColumn('left')" class="ng2-smart-actions">
    <a href="#" *ngIf="grid.getSetting('actions.edit')" class="ng2-smart-action ng2-smart-action-edit-edit" [innerHTML]="grid.getSetting('edit.editButtonContent')" (click)="onEdit(row, $event)"></a>
    <a href="#" *ngIf="grid.getSetting('actions.delete')" class="ng2-smart-action ng2-smart-action-delete-delete" [innerHTML]="grid.getSetting('delete.deleteButtonContent')" (click)="onDelete(row, $event)"></a>
  </td>
  <!--<td *ngIf="row.isInEditing" class="ng2-smart-actions">
    <a href="#" class="ng2-smart-action ng2-smart-action-edit-save" [innerHTML]="grid.getSetting('edit.saveButtonContent')" (click)="onSave(row, $event)"></a>
    <a href="#" class="ng2-smart-action ng2-smart-action-edit-cancel" [innerHTML]="grid.getSetting('edit.cancelButtonContent')" (click)="row.isInEditing = false;"></a>
  </td>-->
  <td *ngFor="let cell of row.getCells()">
    <ng2-smart-table-cell [cell]="cell" [mode]="grid.getSetting('mode')" [inputClass]="grid.getSetting('edit.inputClass')" (edited)="onSave(row, $event)"></ng2-smart-table-cell>
  </td>
  <td *ngIf="row.isInEditing" class="ng2-smart-actions">
    <a href="#" class="ng2-smart-action ng2-smart-action-edit-save" [innerHTML]="grid.getSetting('edit.saveButtonContent')" (click)="onSave(row, $event)"></a>
    <a href="#" class="ng2-smart-action ng2-smart-action-edit-cancel" [innerHTML]="grid.getSetting('edit.cancelButtonContent')" (click)="row.isInEditing = false;"></a>
  </td>
  <td *ngIf="!row.isInEditing && grid.showActionColumn('right')" class="ng2-smart-actions">
    <button><a href="#" *ngIf="grid.getSetting('actions.edit')" class="ng2-smart-action ng2-smart-action-edit-edit" [innerHTML]="grid.getSetting('edit.editButtonContent')" (click)="onEdit(row, $event)"></a></button>
    <button><a href="#" *ngIf="grid.getSetting('actions.delete')" class="ng2-smart-action ng2-smart-action-delete-delete" [innerHTML]="grid.getSetting('delete.deleteButtonContent')" (click)="onDelete(row, $event)"></a></button>
    <button><a href="#" *ngIf="grid.getSetting('actions.activate')" class="ng2-smart-action ng2-smart-action-delete-delete" [innerHTML]="grid.getSetting('activate.activateButtonContent')" (click)="onActive(row, $event)"></a></button>
  </td>
  <td>Yogesh</td>
</tr>

<tr *ngIf="grid.getRows().length == 0">
  <td [attr.colspan]="grid.getColumns().length + (grid.getSetting('actions.add') || grid.getSetting('actions.edit') || grid.getSetting('actions.delete'))">test {{ grid.getSetting('noDataMessage') }}</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
```

Comment: constructor(public service:ViewListCustomerServiceService) is correct?? or maybe constructor(public service:ViewListCustomerService) this?

Comment: Can you provide more code of your `Ng2SmartTableComponent`, et al the  html.

Comment: i added all code of Ng2SmartTableComponent. please check

Comment: now one thing i found that the table is executed before response come from service. Please suggest me how can i stop the execution of Ng2SmartTableComponent till getting the response from service.

Comment: sry i did not have internet in the last few days.
Can you provide your Ng2SmartTableComponent *HTML* file?

Comment: Yes, i added now.

Comment: Does the answer work? Or do you still have the problem

Answer (score 0):

Your method call `getCustomerItemList()` is not finished at the moment your Ng2SmartTable component will be created and that's the cause of your error message, i think.
I would suggest something like following:

```
<ng2-smart-table *ngIf="source" [settings]="settings" [source]="data" [defaultSettings]="defaultSettings" [customerDetailsItem]="customerDetailsItem"></ng2-smart-table>
```

Through the *ngIf, your component will be only created, if your Observable has finished and source is not undefined anymore.

Comment: in above solution instead of keeping *ngIf="source" i kept *ngIf="data" then my table is working properly.   Thanks Batajus and all.